# error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' on lines 26,36

Tags: c++

I am working on reading a file and formatting array so I can work on them with other stuff but I am stuck in the beginning. It says I can't change from char* to char but my token is not char*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void get_input(string teams[][2]) {
    string infile;
    double value;   
    char buffer[100];
    char token;
    stringstream ss;
    cout << "Enter the input file: ";
    cin >> infile;
    ifstream file;
    file.open (infile.c_str());
    if (file.is_open()) {
        int teamcounter = 0;
        while (file.getline (buffer, 100)) {
            int counter = 0;
            token = strtok (buffer, ",");
            while (token) {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    teams[teamcounter][counter] = token;
                }
                else if ((counter == 1) || (counter == 2)) {
                    ss << token;
                    ss >> value;
                    teams[teamcounter][counter] = value;
                }
                token = strtok (NULL, ",");
                counter++;
            }
            teamcounter++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file"; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<2;j++){
            cout << teams[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Is making my array into string make me unable to put float or double values to them?

```
int main() {
    cout << "Welcome to the football bracket game!" << endl;
    string teams[7][2];
    get_input(teams);
}
```

My input text format is like this:

```
Trojans, 0.80, 0.60
Bruins, 0.20, 0.30
Bears, 0.60, 0.50
Trees, 0.50, 0.40
Ducks, 0.40, 0.80
Beavers, 0.50. 0.10
Huskies, 0.80, 0.40
Cougars, 0.10, 0.90
```

Comment: Do you know where the error is coming from? Can you show us?

Comment: Well, certainly you cannot put a float or a double into a char, but you can convert a float or a double into a string and then store that. The error is coming because strtok returns a char* and you are trying to store this in the char variable token.

Comment: declaring token as char* gives me segmentation error. Also, if I store numbers as string, how do I use them as float?

Comment: @user3317141: Creating a compile error is not the way to fix a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

```
char token;
token = strtok (buffer, ",");
```

`token` is of type `char`, `strtok` returns a `char*`. They are not of the same type and the compiler is complaining (logically) about it. `strtok` returns the pointer to the next token of the processed input `char*` so indeed there's no sense in assigning it to a single character.

Compiler is indeed unable to find a way to convert from the returnd `char*` to `char`, there's nothing strange in the error.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` returns a `char*` but your `token` variable is declared as `char`.  It needs to be declared as `char*` instead.

**Update**: Since you are using C++, I strongly suggest you use C++, don't mix C and C++ together. Ignore `strtok()` even exists, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Team
{
    std::string Name;
    double Value1;
    double Value2;
};

void get_input(std::vector<Team> &teams)
{
    std::string infile;
    std::ifstream file;

    std::cout << "Enter the input file: ";
    std::cin >> infile;

    file.open (infile.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file"; 
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        Team team;
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        std::string token;
        int counter = 0;

        while (std::getline(ss, token, ","))
        {
            switch (counter)
            {
                case 0:
                    team.Name = token;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    std::stringstream(token) >> team.Value1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    std::stringstream(token) >> team.Value2;
                    break;
            }
            ++counter;
        }
        teams.push_back(team);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to the football bracket game!" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Team> teams;
    get_input(teams);

    for (std::vector<Team>::iterator iter = teams.begin(); iter != teams.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->Name << ": " << iter->Value1 << " " iter->Value2 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried declaring token as char *, but it gives me segmentation fault when I execute. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: A segfault means you are accessing invalid memory. The only way that could happen in `strtok()` is if `buffer` is invalid, like if it is not null terminated. Another problem is that the second dimension of `teams` takes 2 elements, but you are allowing `counter` to go to 3, exceeding the bounds of that second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You defined variable token as having type `char`

```
char token;
```

while function strtok returns an obhect of type `char *` .So these statements

```
token = strtok (buffer, ",");
```

and

```
token = strtok (NULL, ",");
```

are invalid. I think you meant

```
char *token;
```

Also you defined array teams as an array of elements of type `std::string`

```
string teams[7][2];
```

However in function get_input you try to assign a value of type double to an object of type std::string

```
double value;
//...
teams[teamcounter][counter] = value;
```

Also it would be more correct if the function had second parameter that specifies the size of the first dimension of the array

```
void get_input(string teams[][2], int n );
```

and would be called as

```
get_input(teams, 7);
```

You should check how many lines of the file you entered.